# What's the difference between Sniper Elite: Nazi Zombie Army 1 and 2?

Tags: sniper-elite-v2, nazi-zombie-army

What is the difference between the two game parts of Nazi Zombie Army?

Comment: Could've done some research yourself, mention your research results in the question and ask for confirmation/additional information that you might've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, Nazi Zombie Army 2 is the sequel to Nazi Zombie Army 1.

The story starts almost immediately after the ending of the first game. There are new enemies as well as new environments. Without spoiling, I would say NZA2 is more hellish, fire everywhere, darker. NZA1 has a more traditional WW2 look, more similar to the Sniper Elite V2 original game.

Gameplay is identical. Consider them as episodes, not 2 different games.

[The second one](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/sniper-elite-nazi-zombie-army-2) is usually rated lower than [the first one](http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/sniper-elite-nazi-zombie-army), mainly because it is lacking evolution.

Comment: So no gameplay enhancements/regressions other than the story/new enemy types??

Comment: @deutschZuid I edited my post to consider your comment.